# How to show original full list of data after doing Search in Jquery DataTables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Jquery dataTable as below.  It works fine except that if I do a Search on the Search field, the users displayed were narrowed down to match the search criteria, but there is no way for me to go back and let the dataTable to show the original full list of users unless I do another search on the Search field. Is there a way to change this behavior so that I can see a full list of users without doing the search again ? Thanks a lot!

```
var input = 
{
   "aaData": data,              
   "aoColumns": 
   [{      
       "mDataProp": "userid",
       "sWidth": "10%"
     },
     {
       "mDataProp": "fullname",
       "sWidth":"15%"
     }
 ]
 };                        

   $("#users").dataTable(input);
```

I have added the following code which worked:

```
<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset Table"></input> 
$('#btnReset').click(function()
{
    var oTable = $('#users').DataTable();
    oTable.search('').draw();
});
```

Comment: I can't think of another way of doing so but clearing the search `input`.

Comment: @Wahyu Kodar, Thank you.  Any sample code?

Comment: Looking at the default behavior of the library it is removing rows from the dom, so CSS shouldn't have an effect. Can you clarify the functionality you're looking for jlp? Clearing the search term isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @david s, not really, the customer doesn't want to do Search again to get the original list back.  I think I can add some kind of button to the dataTable to do it.  The question is how to do it, is there an easy way or build-in functionality of dataTable to accomplish that so that the original full list of users can be brought back easily.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, let's give this a shot...

Create a new 'reset' button somewhere on the page, link this functionality to it...

```
$('#users').search('').draw();
```

That will mimic what happens when a user manually removes the search term, but now they can do it with the click of a button instead.

You could also look into using state to implement this, if that suits you better: https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

Comment: I created a reset button, and added a click function with "$('#users').search('').draw();"  but it didn't remove the search term and the table not restored.  Any idea ?

Comment: Without seeing the entirety of your code it will be tricky to debug. Can you throw something more substantial on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Thank you..  Never used jsfiddle.net before.  I will try it but for now, I have put the added code in the original post

Comment: do I need to install some plug-ins in order for the $('#users').search('').draw();" to work ?

Comment: Did you put the script right below the input element? It needs to be wrapped in a script tag.

`<input/><script type="text/javascript>code...</script>`

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional plugins. I made the assumption you're using the latest version (v1.10.5) of the datatables jQuery plugin (https://www.datatables.net/download/index)

Comment: I downloaded 1.10.5 datatable version just now.  I will try again. but why I need to put the <script> tag right below the input element?  I am using jQuery's .click to detect when the Reset button is clicked and the .click function is within the <script> section of the file along with other functions.

Comment: I updated code and posted in the original post up there.  I moved the code handling the reset button right below the Reset button <input>, but still, the table didn't get re-drawn.  The alert was printed though.

Comment: problem solved.  Had to use DataTable(). instead of dataTable()  Thanks a lot for the help.